# Old kernels reapear in jupyter even after reinstallation

Tags: kernel, jupyter

I had tried to get a ijavascript kernel running (but failed).
Now I want to remove it from the available kernels in jupter (lab and notebook).

I ran:

```
jupyter kernelspec remove kernel-name

jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
    python3    /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

shows, that the kernel is "gone".

I looked into: "/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/kernel.json" and every "kernel.json" file I could find in the installation folder or my homefolder. Only the python 3 kernel is shown.

However the Javascript kernel is shown in the jupyter lab starter and as available kernel in jupyter notebook (both in jupyterhub).
It still shows up after a complete reinstallation of anaconda. (After having deleted the previous installation files and all config-files and and folders I could find.)

How can I get rid of this kernel entry?

Installation:
ubuntu 18.4
Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64
Jupyter 4.40
Jupyterhub 0.9.4
Jupyterlab 0.35.4

Answer (score 3):

After some more digging I found 
[the following places for possible kernel definitions](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernelspecs).

Although I removed the kernel definition which I found in

```
/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels
```

this was not enough for jupyterhub (installed as root).

Logging in into jupyterhub with my user account still showed the kernel.
I finally found it in my user home directory under:

```
~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels
```

Removing this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac mine was in `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels` as found in Siegfried's link.

```
$ cd ~/Library/Jupyter/
$ rm -r /kernels
```

Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

under Windows it might be in the directory

> C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels